# Car Identification - MPV with at least second row of seats reversible - UK/EU only

Tags: vehicle-identification, mpv

I know this is not, really, the question for this site, but I'm out of ideas. Every search on Google ends me up on a website about baby carseats (not the same, obviously, but the trend is there) or on, literally, two or three sites where ppl ask same question.

I need to find a car, where the second row of seats can be reversed. Not to elaborate too much, but I'm looking for a car which can transport 5-6 people with decent amount of luggage. Since our family is in the expansion phase and the plan is for it not to be the last... There is a need. Also, we plan to do a lot more moving around in that car, not necessarily UK only, so it's time to invest in a new vehicle on a long-term basis. So new or no more than 5 years old.

And this is where the reversible seats come to play. I never had an accident before (serious, I mean), but adding yet more miles to my odometer I want to play it safe when (not if) probability rears it's ugly head. So, kids should travel RWF for way more than first 18 months, yet there is very little car seats available in RWF config for older children. And those that are are quite expensive (easily top £500-£700 apiece). So, its way more cheaper to get standard car seat (with 5-point-restraining) and put it on a seat that's turned around and, obviously, it's way more flexible in almost any circumstances, not to mention that it's more efficient in using available space.

So, What I know is that only three cars are available to me under above criteria:

1. VW Caravelle - which is out of the question financially.
2. Toyota Previa (MK1 and MK2), not sure about newer ones, but those would also pretty expensive
3. SssanYong Rodius MK1 - perfect fit, including isofix mounting, yet unfamiliar with the manufacturer quality/reliability-wise

Notable mentions:

4. Renault Espace - but as far as I know, the seats can be reversed only while parking; one cannot travel with seats in RWF position.
5. Chrysler Grand Voyager - it was available with reversible seats in one package only, not offered anymore, it was anyway quite rare, and available info doesn't say if those seats are rated for RWF travel.

Anyone know more, please?

Comment: the renault espace as available now is apparently LHD only...

Comment: Ford Taurus wagon?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist - I'm sorry? I don't believe it's even an MPV, let alone with reversible seating in second  row? And isn't station wagon a pre-2000 model? Does not qualify on any of the characteristics mentioned in question, unless it's Chinese manufacturing of this year, which I don't know about...

Comment: Your motivation for this seems odd. Yes, baby seats should be reversed, but once they are into child seats, the risk you are looking to mitigate by facing them backwards is not really a problem. Instead, just get good car seats - for my 3 I had Recaros, with excellent head restraints and side protection.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - you are incorrect. In most accident with children studies show that RWF for as long as posible is preferable for several reasons: 1. Violent whiplash is not a concern, and babies don't have enough muscle strength to survive that up to 5-6Y in FWF, 2. FWF car seats have very limited backrest adjustment range, which is a necessity from design POV. with RWF you can go much more horizontal, critical when long travelling. 3. RWF over 0 is very space-consuming. In the car we have (compact) my kid doesn't have enough leg room right now, and she's 3Y in FWF. Going RWF is impossible

Comment: Ford transit custom business

Comment: @Myself - Excellent find, thank you. Unfortunately it's rather newer design and at the price of £42 k  pretty much out of the question. But adding to the list

Comment: I'd like to see the studies. The ones I looked at showed negligible correlation after 2yrs. I'd focus much more on other safety aspects which will have a greater impact on the safety of your children.

Comment: But as you are after them, you also have the Tesla, and the Nissan X-Trail and others.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Here it is. It's not direct linking, but all the information is there:
http://thecarseatlady.com/5-times-safer/ https://www.carseat.co.uk/rear-facing-5x-safer/ https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2598309/ (this one is retracted, but due to issues with very small data sample authors say can't replicate results; the idea is still valid though). As for your recommendations - thank you, but unable to follow through due to financial restraint.